# pySerial 2.6: specify end-of-line in readline()

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial

I am sending commands to Eddie using pySerial. I need to specify a carriage-return in my readline, but pySerial 2.6 got rid of it... Is there a workaround?

Here are the [Eddie command set](https://www.parallax.com/sites/default/files/downloads/550-28990-Eddie-Command-Set-v1.2.pdf#page=2) is listed on the second and third pages of this PDF. Here is a [backup image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxqAK.png) in the case where the PDF is inaccessible.

#### General command form:

```
Input:              <cmd>[<WS><param1>...<WS><paramN>]<CR>
Response (Success): [<param1>...<WS><paramN>]<CR>
Response (Failure): ERROR[<SP>-<SP><verbose_reason>]<CR>
```

As you can see all responses end with a `\r`. I need to tell pySerial to stop.

#### What I have now:

```py
def sendAndReceive(self, content):
  logger.info('Sending {0}'.format(content))
  self.ser.write(content + '\r')
  self.ser.flush();
  response = self.ser.readline() # Currently stops reading on timeout...
  if self.isErr(response):
    logger.error(response)
    return None
  else:
    return response
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I'm having the same issue and implemented my own readline() function which I copied and modified from the serialutil.py file found in the pyserial package.

The serial connection is part of the class this function belongs to and is saved in attribute 'self.ser'

```
def _readline(self):
    eol = b'\r'
    leneol = len(eol)
    line = bytearray()
    while True:
        c = self.ser.read(1)
        if c:
            line += c
            if line[-leneol:] == eol:
                break
        else:
            break
    return bytes(line)
```

This is a safer, nicer and faster option than waiting for the timeout.

EDIT:
I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10222788/line-buffered-serial-input) post when trying to get the io.TextIOWrapper method to work (thanks [zmo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1290438/zmo)).
So instead of using the custom readline function as mentioned above you could use:

```
self.ser = serial.Serial(port=self.port,
                         baudrate=9600,
                         bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
                         parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
                         stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
                         timeout=1)
self.ser_io = io.TextIOWrapper(io.BufferedRWPair(self.ser, self.ser, 1),  
                               newline = '\r',
                               line_buffering = True)
self.ser_io.write("ID\r")
self_id = self.ser_io.readline()
```

Make sure to pass the argument `1` to the `BufferedRWPair`, otherwise it will not pass the data to the TextIOWrapper after every byte causing the serial connection to timeout again.

When setting `line_buffering` to `True` you no longer have to call the `flush` function after every write (if the write is terminated with a newline character).

EDIT:
The TextIOWrapper method works in practice for *small* command strings, but its behavior is undefined and can lead to [errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24498048/python-io-modules-textiowrapper-or-buffererwpair-functions-are-not-playing-nice) when transmitting more than a couple bytes. The safest thing to do really is to implement your own version of `readline`.

Comment: This is so nice, thank you.  The TextIOWrapper approach has always given me headaches, I don't know why I never thought of implementing such a simple custom readline function.  It works perfectly!

Answer (score 11):

From pyserial 3.2.1 (default from debian Stretch) **read_until** is available. if you would like to change cartridge from default ('\n') to '\r', simply do:

```
import serial
ser=serial.Serial('COM5',9600)
ser.write(b'command\r')  # sending command
ser.read_until(b'\r')   # read until '\r' appears
```

`b'\r'` could be changed to whatever you will be using as carriadge return.

Comment: This a short and the best answer. Y=I tested using serial_for_url('socket://.... using '\r\n' as EOL and it works. Thanks Zhang

Comment: For some reason ser.read_until('\r') didn't work for me. However ser.read_until(serial.serialutil.CR) did work.

Comment: This is the best answer. @Onderbetaald you need to specify it as a byte: b'\r'

Comment: The only answer that works for me. Spent some time figuring what's going on. b'\r' is definitely a must on python3. Figured it out myself, then found out that @rdh has also reported that.

Comment: btw `CR` suggested by @Onderbetaald is defined as `CR = to_bytes([13])` which is exactly the same thing as `b'\r'`

Answer (score 5):

from pyserial's [documentation](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/shortintro.html):

(sic)

> Note:
>
> The `eol` parameter for `readline()` is no longer supported when
> pySerial is run with newer Python versions (V2.6+) where the module
> `io` is available. EOL
>
> To specify the `EOL` character for `readline()` or to use universal
> newline mode, it is advised to use `io.TextIOWrapper`:
>
> ```
> import serial
> import io
> ser = serial.serial_for_url('loop://', timeout=1)
> sio = io.TextIOWrapper(io.BufferedRWPair(ser, ser))
>
> sio.write(unicode("hello\n"))
> sio.flush() # it is buffering. required to get the data out *now*
> hello = sio.readline()
> print hello == unicode("hello\n")
> ```

Comment: the io module docs say: 

`Warning: BufferedRWPair does not attempt to synchronize accesses to its underlying raw streams. You should not pass it the same object as reader and writer; use BufferedRandom instead.`

So I'm not sure this is an entirely Kosher solution. Works though!

Answer (score 1):

reading 10 data from port 3 with board rate 38400, The data is separated with \n character when comes in the incoming data

```
import serial as self
ser=self.Serial("COM3", 38400)  
buffer = []
count = 0.0
c = "\0"
while count < 10:
    c = "\0"
    if ser.inWaiting():
        while True:
            val = ser.read(1)
            if "\n" in val:
                break
            else:
                c += val
        buffer.append(c) # stores all data received into a list   
        count += 1
print buffer
```

Answer (score -3):

It seems that the timeout occurs because `readline()` waits for an `'\n'` character to come from the serial device, which it never sends.

According to the [pyserial documentation](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/pyserial_api.html), you can specify the end of line character:

```
response = self.ser.readline(eol='\r')
```

Does that work?

Comment: The signature for the function was changed for 2.6. I have stated this above. `readline(size=None, eol='\n')` as changed to `readline(size=None)`