# Python io module's TextIOWrapper or BuffereRWPair functions are not playing nicely with pySerial

Tags: python, io, pyserial, python-unicode

I'm writing a serial adapter for some scientific hardware whose [command set](http://www.sutter.com/SOFTWARE/USBv3.pdf) uses UTF-8 character encodings. All responses from the hardware are terminated with a carriage return (u'\r'). I would like to able to use pySerial's `readline()` function with an EOL character specified, so I have this setup, ala [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16470903/pyserial-2-6-specify-end-of-line-in-readline):

```
import serial
import io

ser = serial.Serial(port='COM10', baudrate=128000)
sio = io.TextIOWrapper(io.BufferedRWPair(ser, ser, 1), encoding='utf-8', newline=u'\r')

ser.open()

# these commands move to coordintes (25000, 0, 25000)
cmd = 'M\x80\x1a\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80\x1a\x06\x00'
ucmd = u'M\x80\x1a\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80\x1a\x06\x00'

#this works
ser.write(cmd)
print sio.readline()

#this does not
sio.write(ucmd)
sio.flush()
print sio.readline()
```

Strangely, the first command string (non-unicode using pySerial directly) elicits the correct behavior from the hardware. The second (unicode via Python's io module) causes it to move erratically and then hang. Why would this be? Sending unicode command strings to the hardware does work **IF** the command string is only a couple of a characters. Once you start sending bytes with `hex(ord(byte))` values > 0x7F (outside ASCII range), then you start running intro trouble. I can work around this problem without too much trouble, but would like to know what is going on. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [io docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.BufferedRWPair):

> BufferedRWPair does not attempt to synchronize accesses to its
>   underlying raw streams. **You should not pass it the same object as
>   reader and writer**; use [BufferedRandom](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.BufferedRandom) instead.

I'm guessing that's your problem, as you are passing same object `ser` as reader and writer. BufferendRandom doesn't look like it quite fits the bill either.

So is your problem with `serial` that it hangs waiting for the EOL?

Comment: Derp, thanks! I took it for granted that the examples I was following were principled solutions... I guess they must not have been sending very long command strings.