# Python: serial.readline() - how to define the EOL from \n to \n\n

Tags: python, serial-port, readline, eol

I'm realy sorry for asking another question here in a day.

The new problem in detail:
I connected an Laser Range Finder from HOKUYO onto my RaspBerryPi.

Connection etc works find, thanks to the serial.py

My only Problem ist, wenn I'm sending a command, I get an echo and a timestamp + \n back.

The data in the buffer looks like this:

```
MD000007200001\n
2Dh1\n
\n\n
```

After this, the sensor transmits the measurement, which locks like

```
MD000007200001\n
2Dh1\n
0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C\n
0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C\n
0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C\n
0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C\n
.....
...
0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C0C\n
\n\n
```

to read these data, at the moment I use readall(). Also tried readlines(). In both cases I got the problem, that have to wait until the timeout, which was set to 1.
This takes too much time for a realtime application and the fact, that this sensor can measure every 120ms. If I set the timeout to 0 I often miss some data and everything collapses, because I need the whole dataset for my caluclation.

I also read, that there was an option to set the EOL of readline like readline(eof='\n\n') but with Python 3.x this won't work.

There seems to be a 2nd Option, writing my own readline-function.

But I'm an absolute beginner in python. so I don't know where I should start.

Propably there are some additional options.

Best regards, A.

Comment: shd be easy to adapt the answers at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16470903/pyserial-2-6-specify-end-of-line-in-readline -- those were looking for an EOL of `\r`, you're looking for `\n\n`, but otherwise it seems the same problem.  Do you need it more fully spelled out?

Comment: that would be cool, yes.
i allready read that answer, but was not able to implement my own readline() function;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adapting the answer at [pySerial 2.6: specify end-of-line in readline()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16470903/pyserial-2-6-specify-end-of-line-in-readline) (which also offers alternatives), one could write a function such as:

```
def readline(a_serial, eol=b'\n\n'):
    leneol = len(eol)
    line = bytearray()
    while True:
        c = a_serial.read(1)
        if c:
            line += c
            if line[-leneol:] == eol:
                break
        else:
            break
    return bytes(line)
```

`a_serial` must be a `serial.Serial` instance built with the proper parameters, of course -- e.g, the default `timeout` of `None` could cause this to block indefinitely if the required `eol` marker is not forthcoming.  This does not appear to be a problem for the OP if I read the question correctly, but, it **is** something to be aware of in general cases.

Comment: Thx, that's it.
Seems that i missunderstood the answer from pySerial 2.6: specify end-of-line in readline(); I thought I had to change the existing function readline from the pyserial lib.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the timeout to `0.12` (or whatever you'd like to make it "realtime") and use `readall()`. Then, you have a number of choices:

1. If you want both `\n` and `\n\n` to count as a delimiter, call `replace("\n\n", "\n")` on the data from `readall()` and divide it up into lines yourself by calling `split("\n")`.
2. If you want only `\n\n` to count as a delimiter, just call `split("\n\n")` on the data from `readall()`.

Comment: thx for that information, but the point is, I don't want any time-dependencis;
the best way would be, when there is any possibility to read from the buffer with readline until an \n\n.

Comment: Well then set the `timeout` to 0. See the docs: http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/pyserial_api.html#serial.Serial.__init__