# read and stock various data from various usb devices in python

Tags: python, usb, sensors, pyserial

I am a beginner in python, and I am trying to read the data from several sensors (humidity, temperature, pressure sensors...) that I connect with a usb hub to my computer. My main goal is to record every five minutes the different values of those sensors and then store it to analyse it.

I have got all the [data sheets and manuals](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/2xfcg0w3gwb6r1i/AAA2dGCqmo_OlUlHn-9B7S2Ea?dl=0) of my sensors (which are from Hygrosens Instruments), I know how they work and what kind of data they are sending. But I do not know how to read them. Below is what I tried, using pyserial.

```
import serial #import the serial library
from time import sleep #import the sleep command from the time library
import binascii

output_file = open('hygro.txt', 'w') #create a file and allow you to write in it only. The name of this file is hygro.txt

ser = serial.Serial("/dev/tty.usbserial-A400DUTI", 9600) #load into a variable 'ser' the information about the usb you are listening. /dev/tty.usbserial.... is the port after plugging in the hygrometer, 9600 is for bauds, it can be diminished
count = 0
while 1:
    read_byte = ser.read(size=1)
```

So now I want to find the end of the line of the data as the measurement informations that I need are in a line that begins with 'V', and if the data sheet of my sensor, it said that a line ends by , so I want to read one byte at a time and look for '<', then 'c', then 'r', then '>'. So I wanted to do this:

```
while 1:
    read_byte = ser.read(size=8) #read a byte
    read_byte_hexa =binascii.hexlify(read_byte) #convert the byte into hexadecimal

    trad_hexa = int(read_byte_hexa , 16) #convert the hexadecimal into an int in purpose to compare it with another int
    trad_firstcrchar = int('3c' , 16) #convert the hexadecimal of the '<' into a int to compare it with the first byte    
    if (trad_hexa == trad_firstcrchar ): #compare the first byte with the '<'    
        read_byte = ser.read(size=1) #read the next byte (I am not sure if that really works)
        read_byte_hexa =binascii.hexlify(read_byte)# from now I am doing the same thing as before
        trad_hexa = int(read_byte_hexa , 16)
        trad_scdcrchar = int('63' , 16)
        print(trad_hexa, end='/')# this just show me if it gets in the condition
        print(trad_scdcrchar)    
        if (trad_hexa == trad_scdcrchar ):    
            read_byte = ser.read(size=1) #read the next byte 
            read_byte_hexa =binascii.hexlify(read_byte)
            trad_hexa = int(read_byte_hexa , 16)
            trad_thirdcrchar = int('72' , 16)
            print(trad_hexa, end='///')
            print(trad_thirdcrchar)    
            if (trad_hexa == trad_thirdcrchar ):    
                read_byte = ser.read(size=1) #read the next byte 
                read_byte_hexa =binascii.hexlify(read_byte)
                trad_hexa = int(read_byte_hexa , 16)
                trad_fourthcrchar = int('3e' , 16)
                print(trad_hexa, end='////')
                print(trad_fourthcrchar)    
                if (trad_hexa == trad_fourthcrchar ):    
                    print ('end of the line')
```

But I am not sure that it works, I mean I think it does not have the time to read the second one, the second byte I am reading, it's not exactly the second one. So that's why I want to use a buffer, but I don't really get how I can do that. I am going to look for it, but if someone knows an easier way to do what I want, I am ready to try it!
Thank you

Comment: Please show us [an example of your code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we can see [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).

Comment: It would also be convenient if you gave an example of *how* the sensors transmit the data over USB.

Comment: I add some informations, I hope it is better now for you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be under the impression that the end-of-line character for that sensor's communication protocol is 4 different characters: `<`, `c`, `r` and `>`. However, what is being referred to is the [carriage return](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return), often denoted by `<cr>` and in many programming languages just by `\r` (even though it looks like 2 characters, it represents *just one* character).

You could simplify your code greatly by reading in the data from the sensors line by line, as the protocol is structured. Here's something to help you get started:

```
import time

def parse_info_line(line):
    # implement to your own liking
    logical_channel, physical_probe, hardware_id, crc = [line[index:index+2] for index in (1, 3, 5, 19)]
    serialno = line[7:19]
    return physical_probe

def parse_value_line(line):
    channel, crc = [line[ind:ind+2] for ind in (1,7)]
    encoded_temp = line[3:7]
    return twos_comp(int(encoded_temp, 16), 16)/100.

def twos_comp(val, bits):
    """compute the 2's compliment of int value `val`"""
    if (val & (1 << (bits - 1))) != 0: # if sign bit is set e.g., 8bit: 128-255
        val = val - (1 << bits)        # compute negative value
    return val                         # return positive value as is

def listen_on_serial(ser):
    ser.readline() # do nothing with the first line: you have no idea when you start listening to the data broadcast from the sensor
    while True:
        line = ser.readline()
        try:
            first_char = line[0]
        except IndexError:  # got no data from sensor
            break
        else:
            if first_char == '@':  # begins a new sensor record
                in_record = True
            elif first_char == '$':
                in_record = False
            elif first_char == 'I':
                parse_info_line(line)
            elif first_char == 'V':
                print(parse_value_line(line))
            else:
                print("Unexpected character at the start of the line:\n{}".format(line))
            time.sleep(2)
```

The `twos_comp` function was [written by travc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9147327/2476444) and you are encouraged to upvote his answer when you have enough reputation and if you intend to use his code (and even if you won't, it's still a good answer, I upvoted it just now). The `listen_on_serial` could be improved as well (many Python programmers will recognize the switch-structure and implement it with a dictionary rather than `if... elif... elif...`), but this is only intended to get you started.

As a test, the following code extract simulates the sensor sending some data (which is line-delimited, using the carriage return as the end-of-line marker), which I copied from the pdf you linked to (*FAQ_terminalfenster_E.pdf*).

```
>>> import serial
>>> import io
>>> 
>>> ser = serial.serial_for_url('loop://', timeout=1)
>>> serio = io.TextIOWrapper(io.BufferedRWPair(ser, ser), newline='\r', line_buffering=True)
>>> serio.write(u'A1A0\r'  # simulation of starting to listen halfway between 2 records
...     '$\r'              # marks the end of the previous record
...     '@\r'              # marks the start of a new sensor record
...     'I0101010000000000001B\r'  # info about a sensor's probe
...     'V0109470D\r'              # data matching that probe
...     'I0202010000000000002B\r'  # other probe, same sensor
...     'V021BB55C\r')             # data corresponding with 2nd probe
73L
>>> 
>>> listen_on_serial(serio)
23.75
70.93
>>>
```

Note that it is [recommended by the pyserial docs](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/shortintro.html#eol) to be using `TextIOWrapper` when the end-of-line character is not `\n` (the *linefeed* character), as was also [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16470903/pyserial-2-6-specify-end-of-line-in-readline).

Comment: Thank you very much! It works now! I was not able to see anything, because I had a wrong baudrate (9600), the first part of the documentation was based on this baudrate. If someone want to see my (ugly) code, just tell me I am still improving it.