# Python serial (pySerial) Reading lines with EOL \r instead of \n

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyserial, carriage-return, eol

I am communicating with an SR830 lock-in amplifier via an RS232 cable. When reading the data as in the following code:

```
import serial

def main():
    ser = serial.Serial(
        port='COM6',
        baudrate=19200,
        parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
        stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
        bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS)
    ser.timeout=1
    ser.write("OUTP? 1 \r\n".encode()) #Asks the Lock-in for x-value
    ser.write("++read\r\n".encode())
    x=ser.readline()
    print (x)
if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

I get a byte string like `b'-3.7486e-008\r'`. However the `ser.readline()` function does not recognise the \r as an EOL. So I have to wait for the timeout every time I read data, which will be troublesome as I want to take a lot of points as fast as I can. And the length of the number changes a lot so I cannot just use `ser.read(12)` for example. I have tried using io.TextIOWrapper but it's not clear to me how to implement it. Here's my attempt:

```
import serial
import io
def main():
    ser = serial.Serial(
        port='COM6',
        baudrate=19200,
        parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
        stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
        bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS)
    ser.timeout=1
    sio = io.TextIOWrapper(io.BufferedRWPair(ser, ser))
    sio.write("OUTP? 1 \r\n") #Asks the Lock-in for x-value
    sio.write("++read\r\n")
    x=sio.readline()
    print (x)
if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

Which just prints a blank space. Any help will be much appreciated, thanks.

EDIT:
Here's my working code after the answers, using the loop:

```
import serial
def main():
    ser = serial.Serial(
        port='COM6',
        baudrate=19200,
        parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
        stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
        bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS)
    ser.timeout=5
    ser.write("OUTP? 1 \r\n".encode()) #Asks the Lock-in for x-value
    ser.write("++read\r\n".encode())
    buffer = ""
    while True:
        oneByte = ser.read(1)
        if oneByte == b"\r":    #method should returns bytes
            print (buffer)
            break
        else:
            buffer += oneByte.decode()
if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pySerial 2.6: specify end-of-line in readline()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16470903/pyserial-2-6-specify-end-of-line-in-readline)

Comment: You need at least `newline='\r'` in that `TextIOWrapper` for it to be of any use, else that will look for `\n` too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about use simple loop for reading?

```
def readData():
    buffer = ""
    while True:
        oneByte = ser.read(1)
        if oneByte == b"\r":    #method should returns bytes
            return buffer
        else:
            buffer += oneByte.decode("ascii")
```

You can check the serialutil.py file from Pyserial package, They use the same way to achieve method `read_until`.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend that as a general solution due to the terrible performance, but now that we're talking about low-speed serial interfaces, it'll probably work.

Comment: You mean `\r`, not `\n`.

Comment: @juhist I use this method for communication with multimeter etc. via RS232 where responses are longer than 100 ms and this has absolutely no impact on performance in this cases.

Comment: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: @juhist fixed again.

Comment: Yeah, I added += and .decode() and it worked! I'll just check the other answers to see what's the fastest. Thanks a lot Erik.

Comment: @Calum Beck I have updated answer, the pyserial use same aproach for the read_until method.

Comment: I also added a break function

Answer (score 6):

Use [`Serial.read_until()`](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html#serial.Serial.read_until) instead:

```py
ser.read_until(b'\r')
```

NB: don't forget the `b` to specify a bytes object rather than a standard string. Otherwise, even if it reads the `'\r'`, the function will block until the connection times out.

Comment: This is definitely the cleanest and simplest way of acheiving this

Answer (score 2):

From [the docs for `readline()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.IOBase.readline):

> The line terminator is always `b'\n'` for binary files; for text files, the `newline` argument to `open()` can be used to select the line terminator(s) recognized.

Of course, you can't use `open` here. But what you can do is use `io.TextIOWrapper` to convert the byte stream into a text stream:

```
ser_text = io.TextIOWrapper(ser, newline='\r')
ser_text.readline()
```

Comment: Is the `BufferedRWPair` needed?

Comment: Hmm, actually, just realised even with that code it still waits for the timeout. I'll just stick with the loop. I can see what's going on that way.

Comment: Why not set the timeout to 0 then?

Comment: Keep getting a `AttributeError: 'Serial' object has no attribute 'read1'` error...

Comment: @spitz: I'd file a bug/feature request against pyserial for that