# How can I change the line terminator (end-of-line character, EOL) in pySerial

Tags: python, pyserial

How can I change the end-of-line (EOL, sometimes called TERMINATOR) character in current versions (>3.4) of PySerial? The [short intro advises to use io.TextWrapper](http://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/shortintro.html#eol), but I have never used the `io` module and the example given in the short intro is pretty far from my use-case. Is there a simpler way? Something like Matlab's

```
s = serial('COM3');
s.Terminator = 'CR';
s.open()
```

I just want to be able to do `readline()` on a device that uses `CR` to indicate a newline.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16470903/pyserial-2-6-specify-end-of-line-in-readline?rq=1), although specifying an ancient 2.6 version in the title, is more than relevant here.

Comment: yeah, it looks like a duplicate now, only filtered to keep the up-to-date stuff. I'll mark it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapting the example from your link, adding `newline` parameter, as described in the docs:

```
>>> help(io.TextIOWrapper)
Help on class TextIOWrapper in module io:

class TextIOWrapper(_TextIOBase)
 ...
 |  
 |  newline controls how line endings are handled. It can be None, '',
 |  '\n', '\r', and '\r\n'.
```

modified sample:

```
import serial
import io
ser = serial.serial_for_url('loop://', timeout=1)
sio = io.TextIOWrapper(io.BufferedRWPair(ser, ser),newline="\r")
```

now `readline` stops when encountering a `\r` char.

Comment: I read up a bit and feel a bit silly now for asking this question. I got tripped up by `serial_for_url('loop://', ...)`, which to me looked like some web stuff I don't need. I did not realize 'loop://' is just for tests, and that I can simply replace it with 'COM3' in my case.